# Hide clickable links inside div when opacity is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I have the `HTML` structure as follows:

```
<div class="boxes workshops wrapl">
    <a href="#" id="showw1" class="workshops-button lfloat">Show it</a>
</div>

<div class="boxes exhibitions">
    <a href="#" id="showex1" class="exhibitions-button lfloat">Show it</a>
</div> 
<div class="boxes gallery">
    <a href="#" id="showex1" class="gallery-button lfloat">Show it</a>
</div>
```

The class `.boxes` are squares set next to one another. There are about `30` boxes.
Initially all the boxes are set to `opacity:1` and all the `-button` class are set at `opacity:0`.

However, then also if I hover my mouse inside the `.boxes`, the links are clickable.

My `.navi` menu:

```
<div id="navi">
    <a href="#"><div id="t0"><span>Home</span></div></a>
    <a href="#"><span>Events</span></a>
    <a href="#"><span>Gallery</span></a>
    <a href="#"><span>Exhibitions</span></a>
</div>
```

My `javascript` code for changing the `opacity`.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var isHome = true;
        $(function () {

            $("#navi a").click(function() {
                c = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                isHome = c=="home";
                if (isHome){
                    $('.events-button, .workshops-button, .gallery-button, .sponsors-button, .hospitality-button, .lectures-button, .exhibitions-button').animate({opacity:0.0},500);
                    $(".boxes").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500 );

                } else {
                    $('.' + c).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500 );
                    $('.' + c + "-button").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500 ).addClass('activehack');
                    $('.activehack').not('.' + c + "-button").animate({opacity: 0.0}, 500 );
                    $('.boxes').not('.' + c).animate({opacity: 0.3}, 500 );
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

How can I remove the `click` event of the `-button` elements when they are not visible?

**EDIT #1**
I don't have to click the `.-button` elements.

When I click `home`, all `.boxes` should appear, but the `<a>..</a>` elements in each `.boxes` must not be clickable. 
Then if I click `.events`, only the `.boxes` with class: `.events` should appear **alongwith** `<a>...</a>` elements having `.events-button` class[and they should be clickable now.]

[The Jsfiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/prateeksachan/qGpML/)

Comment: why are you using opacity and not hide/fadeOut?

Comment: @popnoodles: Because I wanted to use the fadeIn and fadeOut effects. I know that `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` are also dedicated `Jquery` functions. Still, I was just using it.

Comment: fadeIn and fadeOut hide the elements after they reach 0% opacity so you wouldn't have this problem. I've given an answer in context of using opacity instead anyway.

Comment: updated my answer - misread slightly, please check it works.

Comment: @popnoodles: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ueFXY/2/)

```
$('a[class="button"]').click(function(e){ // <--- don't miss this e
    if ($(this).css('opacity')==0) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. I don't have to click `.-button` elements. Please see my edited question.

Comment: *"How can I remove the click event of the -button elements when they are not visible?"* With my code if you click them when they are invisible nothing will happen. When they become visible again, a click will work.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already accepted an answer, but the thing is simply blocking the click event doesn't stop the default behavior - the "hand" icon when you hover over the anchor, indicating something clickable. Really, you should be showing/hiding the anchors, not overriding what happens when they are clicked since *they shouldn't be clickable in the first place*.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jesus_tesh/tKXzf/) that actually shows/hides the links, making them unclickable as a  "side effect" but also the expected behavior for a user.

`$(".boxes a").hide();` is added when the home link is clicked, hiding all anchor tags within the divs.

This is also used when any other nav item is clicked, then `$('.' + c + ' a').show();` is used to show the relevant links.

Comment: Well thanks. I had to accept an answer (or the closest answer) abiding by the rules of SO.:P

Comment: Well, I did post another question of that sort. People were having trouble understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

to unbind unecessary handlers use [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)